# why as3 coder does not use closure?

Tags: actionscript-3

I see many code like this

```
foo.addListener(Event.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:Event):void {
   //...
}
```

but, why not?

```
foo.addListener(Event.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
  //...
});
```

I think the below is better, I am using flex sdk 4.5.1, I don't know if it related with the version, or something about optimizations?

Answer (score 5):

Even in other ECMAScript variants (ok, so JavaScript) it is typically better to bind an event using a reference to a function than to dump in an anonymous function.

The reason it's better to use the first form is when it comes to unbinding the event. If you *have* a reference to the bound event, you can unbind it, otherwise you're stuck having to unbind the event other ways.

---

Other information, **all** functions in ECMAScript are closures. They close over the contained variables and set a new scope. Both examples use closures.

Comment: I remember reading long ago that with AVM it was better to avoid anonymous functions. Performance-wise it was give or take... really dependent on what the function did, but I can't find the reference.

Comment: Additionally, naming your closure allows you to link multiple events to the same functions.

Comment: @JamesTomasino if I need unbind or reuse a handler, I will use a named function. but if needn't, why not use annonymouse

Comment: @JohnGiotta the only thing I care is performance, I really like annonymouse

Comment: class A binds an anonymous function to `click`, class B inherits from class A, class B can't change the handler in any way. class X binds a protected function to `click`, class Y inherits from class X, class Y can change the function as needed. The primary reason to use named handles is for ease of reuse and extensibility.

Comment: @guilin桂林, it's spelled `a n o n y m o u s`.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is not a minor consideration: http://gskinner.com/talks/quick/#52